# ListViewItem style in ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf

I have the following window, which displays a listview.  I defined a style for the ListViewItem:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="listView"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The code behind is simply defined as:

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                listView.Items.Add(i);
            }
        }
```

Now, when I run the app, everything looks good except for the first item in the list view.  For the first item, none of the styles are applied.  If I change my xaml to the below, removing the resource dictionary related lines, it all works correctly:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="listView"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I found some sample code online and those resource dictionary lines were left over after a couple of edits, but I do not understand why if they are present only the first item in the view would not pick up the defined styles.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I noticed that my IsSelected Background color is not being picked up.  If I set it to Green for example, selected items still use the default Windows selected color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had that problem before, apperently ListViewItem's selected background color must be set with

```
<Style.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Gray"/>
</Style.Resources>
```

I've never understood the reason for that.. Perhaps someone else here can explain.

And for the first part, if you put that style in a separate Resource dictionary it will work, like this. (Don't know why you're getting the effect you're getting either)

Dictionary1.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Gray"/>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MainWindow

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel Name="c_dockPanel">
    <ListView x:Name="listView"/>
</DockPanel>
```